# Not able to see binded items to listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I've created a `ListBox` with this structure:

```
<ListBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                         Background="AliceBlue"
                         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding EventInfo}">
```

how you can see I binded the `EventInfo` property that I valorize behind code. This property have the `OnPropertyChange();` implementation as my other properties, and the value setted is got correctly. Anyway, I'm not able to display the binded source:

```
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=League}" />
               <TextBlock Text="test" />
            </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

now the property `League` value isn't displayed also the value test. I really don't understand why. The `League` property exist, and also I've no error in xaml.

What I did wrong?

**UPDATE:**

```
public Models.EventInfo EventInfo
    {
        get { return _eventInfo; }
        set
        {
            _eventInfo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

and in the `Model`

```
public class EventInfo
{
    public string League { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string GameWeek { get; set; }
    public string GameStart { get; set; }
    public string FirstTime { get; set; }
    public string SecondTime { get; set; }
    public string Stadium { get; set; }
    public List<MatchArbiter> Arbiter { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you don't set your own item template, do you see the items? If you don't, do you see a `Binding Error` in the Output window?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I've no xaml error.

Comment: That doesn't really answer either of my two questions. Run the app, and see if there's a Binding Error in the output window. If there isn't, try removing the ItemTemplate, run the app again, and see if the items are shown.

Comment: Are you able to determine what type `EventInfo` is?

Comment: @EdPlunkett is a property of my viewmodel. And about the binding error, I tried to remove the itemTemplate, but same situation.

Comment: Could you be persuaded to *tell* me what type it is? Maybe even paste the definition of the property in your question? Not in a comment.

Comment: @EdPlunkett sure, check my update answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You need to populate `ItemsSource` with a collection, not a single item. Instead of your existing `EventInfo` property, you need a collection property. I'm going to rename it to `EventInfoItems` to keep confusion to a minimum.

```
private ObservableCollection<Models.EventInfo> _eventInfoItems = 
    new ObservableCollection<Models.EventInfo>();

public ObservableCollection<Models.EventInfo> EventInfoItems
{
    get { _eventInfoItems; }
    set
    {
        _eventInfoItems = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Now, somewhere, you're going to have to add some items to that collection if you want anything to appear in the list. You could create a few test items in your viewmodel constructor, just for the time being. Like this:

```
    EventInfoItems.Add(new EventInfo { League = "NBA" });
    EventInfoItems.Add(new EventInfo { League = "Premier League" });
    EventInfoItems.Add(new EventInfo { League = "Serie A" });
```

XAML

```
<ListBox 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
    Background="AliceBlue"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    ItemsSource="{Binding EventInfoItems}"
    >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=League}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

## Update

Turns out OP may have only one item. If that's the case, a ListBox is unnecessary. A `ContentControl` is the right control when you've got only one item and you want to display it with a `DataTemplate`. This XAML will use the original version of the `EventInfo` property:

```
public Models.EventInfo EventInfo
{
    get { return _eventInfo; }
    set
    {
        _eventInfo = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ContentControl 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
    Background="AliceBlue"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    Content="{Binding EventInfo}"
    >
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=League}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll try the code. But note that the event, in this case, is even 1, so no need an observableCollection

Comment: @AgainMe You need a collection to use a ListBox. Why are you using a ListBox if you only have one of them?

Comment: Oh I didn't know this, I guess that I doesn't chose the correct control for this target, which control you suggest for display one item?

Comment: @AgainMe Updated. Quite simple, too.

Comment: I tried your update but I get: ContentControl.ItemTemplate was not recognized. Seems that this property missing.

Comment: @AgainMe Whoops, my bad. Try `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` instead. Answer is updated with that.

Comment: No problem :) thanks for this, I didn't know this control before. Have a nice day!